# GPG Error Updating Ubuntu/Debian Packages in 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, software-update

Here is the error I got by updating the ubuntu 22.04 system which is a fresh installation.

```
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5E3C45D7B312C643
E: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I neither have Spotify installed in my system, but i got this error!
Please help me to reslove this!

Comment: Have you install the key of Spotify repo?

Comment: no this is fresh ubuntu installation

Answer (score 0):

Run this to add the spotify key

```
curl https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_5E3C45D7B312C643.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```